# How to use Vuesax $vs.loading outside of component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

Is there a way to use Vuesax $vs.loading in the router (router.js) file? When I try $vs.loading it is failing with undefined error, also tried with Vue.prototype.$vs.loading but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Although not pretty, you could add the `$vs` object back to the prototype, after instantiating your Vue instance.

```
Vue.prototype.$vs = this.$vs;
```